# Building WSO2 microgateway project hangs when run as System user

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-gateway

Unable to build project when initiated from system user. It Hangs while trying to download .ballerina artifacts.

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\INFORM~2\apps\AGENTC~1\.\..\..\jdk\jre
Generating sources...[DONE]

..................................
There are no new updates available
..................................
Compiling source
 wso2/project:3.1.0

 wso2/jms:0.7.0 [central.ballerina.io -> home repo] [> ] 0/4634315
```

Killing the build and trying again results in below error as artifacts are not completely downloaded.

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\INFORM~2\apps\AGENTC~1\.\..\..\jdk\jre
Generating sources...[DONE]

..................................There are no new updates available
..................................
Compiling source
    wso2/project:3.1.0

BUILD FAILED
error: unable to read balo file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.ballerina\balo_cache\wso2\jms\0.7.0\jms-2019r3-java8-0.7.0.balo. balo file seems to be corrupted.
```

Cleaning .ballerina folder and trying again makes process hang again while trying to download jms-2019r3-java8-0.7.0.balo file.

Comment: Could you please try deleting the folder : C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.ballerina
Seems like the balo files are partially downloaded.

Comment: I did try same issue, and in many environments jms-2019r3-java8-0.7.0.balo is created as 0KB and build command hangs